# Nodejs/express and ejs : rendering

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

Sorry, I don't speak English.

I will try to

When LOGIN=OK => welcome.ejs => hello user_id <= It's success!

When LOGIN=X => welcome.ejs => LOGIN link <= Fail. error

Error message is : Cannot read property 'id' of undefined

I do not know why it does not.
How do I fix the problem?

**welcome.ejs**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>welcome</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>welcome</h1>
<% if (user.id) { %>
<p><%= user.id %> hello!</p>
<% } else { %>
<p><a href="/login">LOGIN</a></p>
<% } %>
</body>
</html>
```

**index.js**

```
router.get('/login', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('login');
});

passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
  done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
  var uid = id;
  pool.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
    connection.query('select * from member where id=?', [uid], function(err, rows) {
        connection.release();
        var user = rows[0];
        if(user.id === id) {
            done(err, user);
        }
    });
  });
});

passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
  function(username, password, done) {
    var uid = username,
            upw = password;
    pool.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
        connection.query('select * from member where id=?', [uid], function(err, rows) {
            connection.release();
            var user = rows[0];
            if(uid === user.id && upw === user.pass) {
                console.log('LocalStrategy', user);
                return done(null, user);
            } else {
                return done(null, false);
            }
        });
      });
    }
));

router.post('/login',
  passport.authenticate('local', { successRedirect: '/welcome',
                               failureRedirect: '/login',
                               failureFlash: false })
);

// here is problem
router.get('/welcome', function(req, res, next) {
  console.log('welcome user', req.user);
  console.log('welcome user.id : ', req.user.id);

  var obj = {user: req.user};
  res.render('welcome', obj);
});
```

Comment: Not sure what purpose you put `connection.release` before

Answer (score 0):

Change welcome file as :

```
<% if (user) { %>
```

instead of

```
<% if (user.id) { %>
```